# Override Laravel queue listener output [Laravel <=5.2 only]

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5

Is there any way to somehow override the output of the queue listener?

`Processed: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call` is not very useful, it would be nice if I could somehow output the actual jobs name, and some parameters for what is actually being processed.

Dug in the code, and `WorkCommand` class uses this line to output name of the job, but my actual job class is not the same job that is used here.

`$this->output->writeln('<error>['.Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').']  Failed:</error> '.$job->getName());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the output by registering your own command with the same signature. When you call `php artisan queue:work`, your command will take precedence.

Just make your command inherit from Laravel's `WorkCommand` and override its `writeOutput()` method:

```
<?php // app/Console/Command/QueueWorkCommand.php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand;

class QueueWorkCommand extends WorkCommand
{
    /**
     * Write the status output for the queue worker.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job  $job
     * @param  bool  $failed
     * @return void
     */
    protected function writeOutput(Job $job, $failed)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And remember to register it with the kernel `app/Console/Kernel.php`.